# Get X months from a previous date and back

Tags: php, date, strtotime

The code below gives me X months from todays date and back, but I want to get the date X months from the 1 st Nov 2012 and back instead. How can this be done?

```
// $nrOfMonths can be 1, 3 and 6

function GetIncidents(nrOfMonths) {

    $stopDate = strtotime('-' . $nrOfMonths .' months');

    ... rest of the code ...
}
```

Comment: [Relative statements are always processed after non-relative statements. This makes "+1 week july 2008" and "july 2008 +1 week" equivalent.](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) So use "1st Nov 2012 - $nrofmonths months"

Answer (score 4):

You can just do:

```
$stopDate = strtotime('1st November 2012 -' . $nrOfMonths .' months');
```

Although, I prefer this syntax:

```
$stopDate = strtotime("1st November 2012 - {$nrOfMonths} months");
```

Therefore, your code should follow this pattern:

```
function GetIncidents(nrOfMonths) {

    //your preferred syntax!

    //the rest of your code

}
```

Comment: You could also pass a second argument to `strtotime` to denote the base timestamp for relative dates. Although the `DateTime` approach seems more appropriate.

Comment: function GetIncidents(nrOfMonths, dateX = "1st November 2012") {

        $stopDate = strtotime($dateX '-' . $nrOfMonths .' months');

        ... rest of the code ...
    } looks better

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes to achieve this.

```
$date = new DateTime('November 1, 2012');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M'); // A month

for($i = 1; $i <= $nrOfMonths; $i++) {
    $date->sub($interval); // Subtract 1 month from the date object
    echo $i . " month(s) prior to November 1, 2012 was " . $date->format('F j, Y');
}
```